# Xubuntu - SD card is only recognized if plugged in before boot

Tags: drivers, mount, xubuntu, sd-card

I have a Samsung Chromebook 3 which was EOL. I removed the write protect screw, flashed full UEFI firmware and installed Gallium OS, which worked well. I wanted something more recent so I installed Xubuntu 20.04 which also is working pretty well (after removing snap) except one small problem I was hoping you all could help me with.

If I plug in an SD card in the internal reader prior to boot, the SD card is mounted once I log in. If I try and plug an SD card in after booting, nothing happens.

Results of `lspci` :

```
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller (rev 35) (prog-if 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SD Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at 9131d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: sdhci-pci
    Kernel modules: sdhci_pci
```

Comment: If you insert the SD card after boot, are there any messages written to `/var/log/syslog`? If the SD reader sends the OS a message to say "I have a new card", then it will appear in that log.

Comment: There is nothing in /var/log/syslog if the sd card is hotplugged. If plugged in at boot I get this:

Comment: Jan 18 20:25:23 crs udisksd[539]: Mounted /dev/mmcblk1p1 at /media/crs/FLIPPER SD on behalf of uid 1000
Jan 18  crs dbus-daemon[836]: [session uid=1000 pid=836] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=981 comm="xfdesktop " label="unconfined")
Jan 18  crs systemd[825]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Jan 18 crs dbus-daemon[836]: [session uid=1000 pid=836] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Jan 18  crs systemd[825]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.

Comment: Sometimes you have to enable hotplugging in the bios.

Comment: @jedi tell me that you have no idea what you are doing without telling me.
UEFI for chromebooks is barebones. There are no options.